# AnimateLayoutChanges fail in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

After I put animateLayoutChanges="true" in my layout, recycler view starts to behave weirdly.

**Default :**

[image]

**After I click couple times on items**

[image]

[image]

Why does recycler view do this ?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?